# Approximate Counting Algorithm with limited updates / writes

Tags: algorithm, statistics, graph-theory, probability, approximation

**Problem**

I want to count the number of page hits that my site gets, without relying on an external service, e.g. [countapi.xyz](https://countapi.xyz/), and without invading user privacy by using Google Analytics.

**Idea**

Cloudflare offers a [Key Value service](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/platform/limits/#kv-limits), which allows me up to:

> 100,000 reads per day
>
> 1,000 writes per day

So, I would like to approximate numbers up to 100,000 using only 1,000 writes. This sounds like the [approximate/morris counting algorithm](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Approximate_counting_algorithm) + [here](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/%7Ehy2/files/approx_counting.pdf), and the more recently improved [counting algorithm](https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.02116).

**Question**

Is there a variant of the Morris counter that optimizes not for size, but for # of updates? If not, how can I find the optimal parameters to approximate 100000 using a counter up to 1000?